# Macbook financing - resale

Tags: macbook-pro

I am potentially going to be buying a MacBook on finance from Apple. As it's my first Mac, I'm not 100% certain it'll be for me and so might re-sell it in the unlikely event it isn't.

If it isn't, am I able to just sell it on or is re-sale not allowed as long as I am still paying Apple?

If I can, am I allowed to use the money I get from the re-sale to re-pay a larger amount off my finance agreement? (E.g., if my finance agreement is for £80 per month and I sell it for £1500, can I say to apple "instead of taking £80 this month take £1500 to pay more off", thus shortening the agreement?)

**Edit**

Just spoke to Apple, for anyone else searching for this answer you **can** pay the finance agreement off early if you do have the funds available.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apple Hardware or Software.

Comment: Apple finance on new Apple hardware has nothing to do with Apple hardware? Right.

Comment: The FAQ says "other Apple products and services" are on-topic.    This is Apple-supplied financing, so seems to qualify under "services".

Comment: This is on-topic, but it would be better to ask Apple this question. Only they can answer these for you, so I an closing it for being unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks. I got through to apple and have updated my question with an answer for anyone else thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think once you finance it, it's yours and you are just paying off a loan to the finance company.  So long as you pay back your loan, the finance company won't care what you do with it.

I have no idea if the loan would be open or not, though; that's a very good question.

Comment: Yea the option to re-pay quicker would be good.